# Single named range over multiple sheets in same Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, named-ranges

In Excel, is it possible to name a range that exists over multiple tabs?

For example, I have a range `B3:C20` in sheets `Tab 1` and `Tab 2`

I tried to name a range `NamedRange1` that referred to

```
='Tab1'!$B$3:$C$20,'Tab2'!$B$3:$C$20
```

which seemed to work successfully.

However, when I did a vlookup `=VLOOKUP(F2, NamedRange1, 2, 0)` I received a `#VALUE!` error.

Am I doing something wrong?  Both values F2 and the NamedRange1 have value types of text.

Comment: It's like calling two different kids named John. Which one did you call? No wonder Excel got confused and threw an error. Can you show us a sample of what you want to achieve? Give us a screenshot of desired output, and we'll see how to achieve that.

Comment: Your `VLOOKUP` formula is missing parentheses. Did you copy pasted the formula directly from Excel? That might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

- Select B3:C20 in Tab1 and in the upper left box (cell address) write:
  Tab1!NamedRange1
- Select B3:C20 in Tab2 and in the upper left box (cell address) write:
  Tab2!NamedRange1

Now use:

```
=Iferror(Vlookup(F2,Tab1!NamedRange1,2,0),Vlookup(F2,Tab2!NamedRange1,2,0))
```

You cannot define the same name in each sheet but when you write the sheet name in the range name you can use it